# Android dev: SecurityException when READ_CONTACTS

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-permissions

I'm new to Android development. Below is what I get when I try to access the contacts.
Debug log:

```
... ...
03-08 17:30:39.622    2330-2330/com.learning.zhanggu.test06 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.learning.zhanggu.test06, PID: 2330
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.learning.zhanggu.test06/com.learning.zhanggu.test06.Test06}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{25e387d9 2330:com.learning.zhanggu.test06/u0a58} (pid=2330, uid=10058) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
... ...
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{25e387d9 2330:com.learning.zhanggu.test06/u0a58} (pid=2330, uid=10058) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
... ...
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:422)
            at com.learning.zhanggu.test06.Test06.fetchContacts(Test06.java:48)
            at com.learning.zhanggu.test06.Test06.onCreate(Test06.java:20)
... ...
```

My manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.learning.zhanggu.test06" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <user-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Test06"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_test06" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My Java file:

```
    public void fetchContacts() {
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() >0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String name = getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                output.append("Name: "+name+"\n");
            }
            textView1.setText(output);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
```

Environment:
Android Studio 1.1.0 on Windows 8.1
Emulator: Nexus_4_API_19, Nexus_5_API_21

I searched web a bit and tried also to put the permission into the activity registration but got no luck so far.

May anyone kindly advice, thank you very much.

Comment: A late thanks to @Ranjith for the grammar correction.

Answer (score 3):

It should be uses-permission, not user

Comment: Thank you @Gabe for quick response, you are exactly right, after changed to "uses-permission" this issue is solved. Thanks again ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It was case sensitivity issue for me.Below code worked for me.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

to

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

its should `<uses`... instead of `<user`..

Try this.... :)